# Big number in C#.NET

Tags: c#, php

I have to create a method that verify if a number follow a certain structure, and it must follow a existing pattern implemented in PHP, but I'm having certain trouble doing thins in C#.NET. When the number went too long I got a System.OverflowException, I'm using **ulong**, take a look:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gera um dígito verificador para um código
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">Código</param>
    /// <returns>Digito verificador</returns>
    public static ulong GenerateTrustID(UInt64 code)
    {
        UInt64 intcode = 1;
        UInt64 endcode = 0;

        foreach (UInt64 number in code.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(Convert.ToInt64).ToArray())
        {
            UInt64 newcode = (number * code * intcode);

            char[] chrcode = newcode.ToString().ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(chrcode);
            intcode = UInt64.Parse((new string(chrcode)));
        }

        if (intcode.ToString().Length < 2)
        { 
            intcode = 04051995;
            intcode = intcode * 88;
        }

        endcode = UInt64.Parse(intcode.ToString().GetLast(2));

        return endcode;
    }
```

And I have to reproduce the code below:

```
/**
 * @brief   Gera uma ID de verificação para um código em um esquema privado.
 * @param   int $code Código para o qual será gerado o ID de verificação
 * @return  int
 */
public function generateTrustID($code){
    $intcode = 1;
    $endcode = null;
    $numbers = array_map('intval', str_split($code));

    foreach($numbers as $number){
        $intcode = (int)strrev($number * $code * $intcode);
    }

    if(strlen($intcode) < 2){
        $intcode = 04051995;
        $intcode = $intcode * 88;
    }

    $endcode = substr($intcode, 0, 2);

    return $endcode;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For really large numbers you can use the [BigInteger Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also read this [article](http://fahadjameel.com/2015/06/24/how-to-use-large-numbers-in-c/) for more information on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) to store numbers Bigger than [UInt64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64(v=vs.110).aspx).

For this work first you must be added `System.Numeric` library to your project references.

and use that like this:

```
BigInteger bigInt = 6546546546556565446;
```